# How to ensure I will stay first author of my paper?

Tags: journals

Some time ago i clumsily wrote a paper about an algorithm.Since i had no experience in scientific writing i gave the paper to a professor with the hope that he would help me improve the presentation.The professor rewrote the paper making some very minor changes in proofs without my consent but allowed me to be "first author" on the paper.Recently i discovered that he put himself as first author in the first author field(that was intended for those who made the greatest contribution) of the  of the journal's form.I feel a bit cheated by this and i am not sure how to proceed to change it if it is possible.I have already sent an email to the professor who agreed to change his "mistake" but i don't trust him at all since he lied to me repeatedly in the past for other matters.
Is it fair to pressure him to add my name as first author(he said he will but did nothing yet) on the submission form if its possible since he rewrote my paper(without my consent) but really added nothing new to my algorithm and its proofs ?
Since the professor is a bit dishonest how can i be sure that he does it without deceiving me in some way?

Comment: "What should I do" [isn't a good question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1205#1205). Maybe you could edit it to clarify what kind of solution you are looking for? "How to ensure I will stay first author of my paper," maybe?

Comment: you are right.I will change it.

Comment: How did the part where he _allowed [you] to be "first author" on the paper_ look like? Could it be that the professor made a simple mistake when submitting the paper, that is, he put his own name first either out of old habits or because he will be the corresponding author (i.e. the author that handles submission, which he obviously does - with your agreement?). This would also fit with him going to correct the "mistake". It could just be that, a mistake. Paper submission forms aren't always easy to see through, some still use the same forms they had in the 80s (at least that is my impression)

Comment: Does the professor's name come before yours in alphabetical order?  (Algorithms papers normally list authors in alphabetical order.)

Comment: Yes.But on the paper my name is first.I allowed the professor to send the paper to a journal(information processing letters) and he added his name first in the first author field of the submission form and also on author ordering field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journal editors don't want to become involved in fights about authorship.  However, it is a very well accepted ethical norm that a paper cannot be published without the consent of all of the authors and that authors can't be dropped from a paper after submission or author ordering changed without the consent of the authors.   It's good editorial practice to contact all of the authors of a paper and check for objections if any such change is proposed by the corresponding author.

Thus you have the "nuclear option" of contacting the editor and telling him/her that this change in author order was counter to your prior agreement with the professor and that you no longer consent to publication. I'd recommend that you start by contacting the editor to find out whether the author order has been fixed by your professor.